# What should my composer.json file look like in production environment?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, production, composer-php

I have a Symfony 2.1 project, with additional bundles installed via composer. I want to deploy it to my production server, but I'm wondering if I need to change any things in the `composer.json` file. Here is my current file content:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.1",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",

        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "ornicar/gravatar-bundle": "dev-master",
        "liip/url-auto-converter-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Should I change the `minimum-stability` setting?

Should I fix every requirement to a single version, without wildcard, or "dev-master"?

Am I supposed to search on http://packagist.org/ the last stable version of each dependency?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the most important is your composer.lock, not so much the composer.json.

Deploy your app on a test server, `php composer.phar install`, then run the tests to ensure everything is ok. If it is indeed ok, just deploy on the production server along with the composer.lock.

This way your deps will be exaclty the same as your test server. This is also useful if you have multiple front server, the composer.lock will ensure everyone uses the exact same code.

You said

> Should I fix every requirement to a single version, without wildcard, or "dev-master"?

This is the role of the composer.lock to "fix" everything. The composer.json is about declaring the dependencies, and handling possible incompatibilities between versions. By default, you should stick with the stable versions, unless you need some fancy new feature in the develop branch, or a bugfixe not yet merged.

Hence, you should version your composer.lock, that's easier for automatic deployment.

Comment: Great answer, but could you elaborate on the "deploy your app" step? Which composer files do I need? Obviously the .phar and .lock files. Do I still need the composer.json? What about the composer_installer.php ?

Comment: @BenjaminBrizzi Well I can't elaborate more the "deploy your app". Composer only take care of dependencies, not your application itself. Usually a "deploy your app" can be a  `git clone`. You still need the `composer.json`, as it contains the deps list. `composer.lock` only specify which versions exactly you want to have installed. I don't know what composer_installer.php is, sorry.